# Shell script to change wallpaper each time the system boots

Tags: linux, shell, debian

I'm trying to write a shell script in Kali Linux with Debian 7.6 x86_64 and GNOME 3.4.2, that changes the background desktop wallpaper each time the system boots getting the files from a directory and selecting them randomly and in a time interval, something like a service or a daemon. I don't want to have to execute it by terminal manually each time I boot, and this is the reason because I opened a question that is very similar like others in this site but not the same. What I do was to put the next line in rc.local before the exit 0 line: sh /etc/my_scripts/wallpaper, wallpaper script contents the code I wrote down.
But it doesn't nothing. I think that the problem is that the operating system can't identify the user effective and real UID and GID, because i'm not executing the script by terminal and it can't access to the environment variables , and as result it doesn't know who creates the process and not changes the wallpaper. I did a C program using the functions seteuid(), setuid(), setegid(), setgid() and the system() function running the same line I putted in rc.local, it doesn't worked too. I tried to LSBize the script too and copy it into /etc/init.d directory, and create the symbolic links to the /etc/rcX.d directories with the update-rc.d command, and programs like desktop-nova or cortina that doesn't works too.
So, what can I do to reach my goal?                                                    Thanks and sorry for my English and extensive text.

```
#!/bin/sh

wallpaper_changer()
{
    wallpapers=/home/linuxsoldier/Pictures/Favorites2/*
    while true
    do
        wallpaper=`ls $wallpapers | shuf -n1 `
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://"$wallpaper"
        sleep 15m
    done
}

wallpaper_changer & #To run it in background.
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you are using seems to have a error. You have to provide the full absolute path of the file while using the gsetting command for setting the background image.

The correct function would be as shown below:

```
wallpaper_changer()
{
    wallpapers=/home/linuxsoldier/Pictures/Favorites2/*
    while true
    do
        wallpaper=`ls -d -1 $wallpapers | shuf -n1 `
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://"$wallpaper"
        sleep 15m
    done
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my code, the ls command outputs the absolute path of the file and save it in the wallpaper variable. The wallpaper variable all the time contents strings like this: /home/linuxsoldier/Pictures/Favorites2/landscape.jpg. And when I replace it in the gsettings command, the file image stays like like this: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/linuxsoldier/Pictures/Favorites2/landscape.jpg that is the correct format to pass a file to the command. I don't think that it could be the problem.